# spring.security forbid curl post request

Tags: curl, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

I develop a demo web site with SSM framework and use spring.security for authentication. I am able to login into the site using post request and obtain data using get request. However, I cannot add data using post request. It is always forbidden. If CSRF is disabled, it is OK. I have tried the following approaches, none of them work.

1. add "X-CSRF-TOKEN: CSRF value" to header.
2. add "_csrf: CSRF value" to header.
3. add _csrf to post request body.

So how can I make post request work with CSRF enabled? Also, I am not sure whether CSRF token needs to be regenerated with different posts. And it is curiously that the login post request works.

- application.properties

  ```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ssm?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
   spring.datasource.username=root
   spring.datasource.password=123456

   mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mybatis/*.xml

   spring.security.user.name=root
   spring.security.user.password=123456

   debug=true
  ```
- SecurityConfig

  ```
   @Configuration
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .formLogin().permitAll();
       }
   }
  ```
- UserController

  ```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/rest/users")
   public class UserController {
       @Autowired
       private UserMapper userMapper;

       @PostMapping
       public void add(@RequestBody User user){
           userMapper.add(user);
       }

       @GetMapping
       public List<User> getAll(){
           return userMapper.findAll();
       }
   }
  ```
- curl script

  ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    host=192.168.44.109:8080
    remote=http://${host}
    login=${remote}/login
    users=${remote}/rest/users/

    csrf=$( \
      curl --url ${login} -L -c cookie.txt 2>&1 \
      |grep _csrf \
      |sed 's/^.*value="\(.*\)".*$/\1/' \
    )
    echo "before login, csrf=${csrf}"

    curl --url ${login} -L -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt -i \
        -d "username=root&password=123456&_csrf=${csrf}"

    curl --url ${users} -L -b cookie.txt -v \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "X-CSRF-Token: ${csrf}" \
        -H "x-csrf-token: ${csrf}" \
        -H "_csrf: ${csrf}" \
        -d "{\"name\": \"name2\"}"

    rm -f cookie.txt
  ```
- Script output

  ```
   before login, csrf=6d7b2d7b-f9aa-4463-ad9b-468082df4d74
   HTTP/1.1 302 
   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D728694163DEEC78DDBC8869DC54C870; Path=/; HttpOnly
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
   Pragma: no-cache
   Expires: 0
   X-Frame-Options: DENY
   Location: http://192.168.44.109:8080/
   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:05:52 GMT

   HTTP/1.1 200 
   Vary: Origin
   Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
   Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
   Pragma: no-cache
   Expires: 0
   X-Frame-Options: DENY
   Content-Type: application/hal+json
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Date: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:05:52 GMT

   {
     "_links" : {
       "profile" : {
         "href" : "http://192.168.44.109:8080/profile"
       }
     }
   }*   Trying 192.168.44.109...
   * TCP_NODELAY set
   * Connected to 192.168.44.109 (192.168.44.109) port 8080 (#0)
   > POST /rest/users/ HTTP/1.1
   > Host: 192.168.44.109:8080
   > User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
   > Accept: */*
   > Cookie: JSESSIONID=D728694163DEEC78DDBC8869DC54C870
   > Content-Type: application/json
   > X-CSRF-Token: 6d7b2d7b-f9aa-4463-ad9b-468082df4d74
   > x-csrf-token: 6d7b2d7b-f9aa-4463-ad9b-468082df4d74
   > _csrf: 6d7b2d7b-f9aa-4463-ad9b-468082df4d74
   > Content-Length: 17
   > 
   * upload completely sent off: 17 out of 17 bytes
   < HTTP/1.1 403 
   < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
   < Pragma: no-cache
   < Expires: 0
   < X-Frame-Options: DENY
   < Content-Type: application/json
   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   < Date: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:05:52 GMT
   < 
   * Connection #0 to host 192.168.44.109 left intact
   {"timestamp":"2021-06-20T11:05:52.540+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path":"/rest/users/"}* Closing connection 0
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**whether CSRF token needs to be regenerated with different posts**

No, it is not necessary.

**And it is curiously that the login post request works**

The token is regenerated by spring.security after login.

**So how can I make post request work with CSRF enabled?**

The critical part is how to obtain the new CSRF token generated after login. One possible solution is to save the CSRF token in cookie. And SecurityConfig should be changed to:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Then, the csrf token can be obtained from cookie by `awk '/XSRF-TOKEN/{print $7}' cookie` and send to the server using X-XSRF-TOKEN request header. The complete script is changed to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

 host=192.168.44.109:8080
 remote=http://${host}
 login=${remote}/login
 users=${remote}/rest/users/

 csrf(){
     awk '/XSRF-TOKEN/{print $7}' cookie
 }

 curl ${login} -c cookie 1> /dev/null 2>/dev/null

 echo "before login, csrf=$(csrf)"
 curl ${login} -d "username=root&password=123456&_csrf=$(csrf)" -b cookie -c cookie -L -i
 echo "after login, csrf=$(csrf)"

 name=$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')
 curl ${users} -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: $(csrf)" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"name\": \"${name}\"}" -b cookie -L -v

 rm -f cookie
```